# `send_mail` method send email, the receive address did not received

Tags: python, django, email

I use the `send_mail` to send email to a list of email addresses, but it seems did not send to the addresses.

My key code are bellow:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

result = send_mail(subject, message, from_email, to_email_list, fail_silently=False)

print(result)  # there prints `1`
```

My email settings in settings.py is bellow:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.qq.com'   # QQ:smtp.qq.com   163:smtp.163.com
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'qiyunserveremail@qq.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'qiyunserver_password'  
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
```

and the traceback is bellow:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Subject: =?utf-8?b?5Li76aKY?=
From: qiyunserveremail@qq.com
To: lxt123@126.com
Date: Thu, 30 Nov 2017 03:02:26 -0000
Message-ID: <20171130030226.15096.58930@aircraftdemacbook-pro.local>

内容
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  # this is the  print(result)
```

---

**EDIT**

And I login my EMAIL_HOST_USER email, in the sent email section, there is no email there.

**EDIT-2**

I tried change `EMAIL_USE_TLS=True` to `EMAIL_USE_SSL=True` but do still not work.

Comment: To trace this problem, login to your email, and check `sent mail` section. If your emails appear there, it means that is not your fault.

Comment: `smtp.qq.com` seems do not support `TLS` but only `SSL`. And generally `TLS`'s port is 587.

Comment: @Sraw See my EDIT-2

Comment: Try to use plain lib `smtplib` to test connection.